# Possible import error after updating to SDK 33

Tags: react-native, expo

I've upgraded to expo SDK 33 from SDK 32 and I am getting the following error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.
>
> Check your code at App.js:117.,

My App.js looks like this(simplified)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { Root } from "native-base";
import {
    StackNavigator,
    addNavigationHelpers,
} from 'react-navigation';
import {
    createStore,
    applyMiddleware,
    combineReducers,
    compose
} from 'redux';
import {
    createReduxBoundAddListener,
    createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware,
} from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import {
    moveTo,
    moveBack,
    moveAndResetStack,
    showSupport,
    hideSupport,
    startLoading,
    stopLoading
} from './src/store/actions/index';
import { Notifications } from 'expo';

import { StyleProvider } from 'native-base';
import getTheme from './native-base-theme/components';
import platform from './native-base-theme/variables/platform';

// reducers
import routesReducer from './src/store/reducers/routes';

// Global headers
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator';
import { State } from './src/modules/State';
import events from './src/events/events';

const navReducer = (state,action) => {
    const newState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
    return newState || state;
}


const appReducer = combineReducers({
    ...
});

const middleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
    "root",
    state => state.nav,
);

const addListener = createReduxBoundAddListener("root");


class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isReady: false,
        }
    }

    async componentWillMount()
    {
        this.setState({isReady: true});

        Notifications.addListener(this.handleNotification)
    }

    handleNotification(notification)
    {
        events.publish('displayNotification', notification);
    }


    render()
    {
        if (!this.state.isReady) {
            return <Expo.AppLoading /> ;
        }
        return (
            <Root>
                <StyleProvider style={getTheme(platform)}>
                    <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
                        dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
                        state: this.props.nav,
                        addListener,
                    })} />
                </StyleProvider>
            </Root>
        );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    nav: state.nav
});


const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App);

let composeEnhancers = compose;

if (__DEV__) {
    composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
}

const ww = createWw(appReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, middleware)));

export default class Top extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider ww={ww}>
                <AppWithNavigationState />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at file './src/store/actions/index' and  './src/events/events'
It seems there are something not properly exported from there.

Comment: I couldn't see anything. The thing is that it worked fine in sdk 32. Has anything changed about the exports?

Comment: I updated from 33 to 34 today. It is not as smooth as I expected. 

I finally run 'expo init' to init a new project after I upgraded expo to latest version by 'npm install -g expo-cli'. Then I compare the new package.json with the one in my project, and update modules versions that changed. Then after 'npm install', my project works again, without change any code. FYI.